# ColorDrawable is always purple when displayed in Caldroid calendar cell

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, colordrawable

I am working on a calendar for an app. I'm using Caldroid. On some dates I would like to change the background color. If the date I would like to color differently is also the current date, then I want a red border on the cell as well as that color. However, all the drawables I try to display always turn up purple. Why is this? My logic to display the drawable looks like this:

```
ColorDrawable black = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.black);
        ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.green);
        ColorDrawable yellow = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.yellow);
        ColorDrawable blue = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.blue);

        ColorDrawable blackBordered = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.red_border_for_black);
        ColorDrawable greenBordered = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.red_border_for_green);
        ColorDrawable yellowBordered = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.red_border_for_yellow);
        ColorDrawable blueBordered = new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.red_border_for_blue);

        if(differenceInDatesGreen < differenceInDatesBlack) {
            if (datesEqual(today.toString(), trashDay.toString())) {
                Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "greenBordered");
                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(greenBordered, trashDay);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "green");
                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(green, trashDay);
            }
        } else {
            if (datesEqual(today.toString(), trashDay.toString())) {
                Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "blackBordered");
                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blackBordered, trashDay);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "black");
                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(black, trashDay);
            }
        }

        if (datesEqual(today.toString(), neighborhoodEvent.toString())) {
            Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "yellowBordered");
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(yellowBordered, neighborhoodEvent);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "yellow");
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(yellow, neighborhoodEvent);
        }

        if (datesEqual(today.toString(), neighborhoodEvent.toString())) {
            Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "blueBordered");
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blueBordered, specialEvent);
        } else {
            Log.d("Where in caldroid fragment setter", "blue");
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue, specialEvent);
        }

        caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.White, trashDay);
        caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.White, neighborhoodEvent);
        caldroidFragment.setTextColorForDate(R.color.White, specialEvent);
```

All my drawable XML code is exactly the same, except for color differences.
The drawable for black without a red border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="@color/Black" />

        <solid android:color="@color/Black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The drawable for black with a red border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/Red_For_Border" />

        <solid android:color="@color/Black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

All help appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi @OwenScott, welcome to stackoverflow.com.  Can give a more minmal example that results in the wrong color? (Note i'm not familiar with Caldroid, so if this is minimal than leave it as it.)

Answer (score 0):

The `ColorDrawable(int)` constructor expects a *color value*; you are passing it a *resource id*.

Correct usage would be one of the following:

```
new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_color));

new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);

new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
```